# WebSphere 7 invoking multiple threads in Struts 1.2

Tags: thread-safety, websphere, threadpool, struts-1, critical-section

Intermittent failure to download the reports.  Front end Error: Internal Server Error - 500.

On click of the download, the control goes to the action class. Sometimes after approx. a minute, another thread gets invoked automatically without any frontend operation and then the two threads run in the action class that throws the 500 Server error on the frontend.

Has anyone encountered such an issue?

Struts config snippet:

```
<action input="/Report_Selection.jsp" name="ReportForm" path="/report" scope="session" type="com.ReportAction">
    <forward name="Download" path="/DownloadReportAction.do"/>
    <forward name="failure" path="/Report_Selection.jsp"/>
    <forward name="exception" path="/Error.jsp"/>
</action>
<action name="ReportForm" path="/DownloadReportAction" scope="session" type="com.DownloadReportAction">
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Solved it after days of hardwork... 
culprit was a setting (ServerIOTimeout) in plugin-config.xml